# Puppet Facts to retrieve instanceProfileArn

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am working on a script that would require passing the Instance profile arn. I have been using puppet to retrieve some information using its facter capability. Below is an (snippet)example of a facter output found online, the full output can be found here (https://gist.github.com/cliff-wakefield/b232ef51799908a0264eb7e95af09092). What I'd like to obtain is the "InstanceProfileArn"

```
ec2_metadata => {
  ami-id => "ami-34281c57",
  ami-launch-index => "0",
  ami-manifest-path => "(unknown)",
  block-device-mapping => {
    ami => "/dev/sda1",
    root => "/dev/sda1"
  },
  hostname => "ip-10-180-0-40.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal",
  iam => {
    info => "{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2016-08-28T23:12:36Z",
  "InstanceProfileArn" : "arn:aws:iam::750105279227:instance-profile/AnexPrereqs-AnexIAMInstanceProfile-11O8QJAS4XO7S",
  "InstanceProfileId" : "AIPAI6YKKPRVVX2XD6LCK"
}"
```

By running `facter ec2_metadata.iam.info`, I get:

```
{
      "Code" : "Success",
      "LastUpdated" : "2016-08-28T23:12:36Z",
      "InstanceProfileArn" : "arn:aws:iam::750105279227:instance-profile/AnexPrereqs-AnexIAMInstanceProfile-11O8QJAS4XO7S",
      "InstanceProfileId" : "AIPAI6YKKPRVVX2XD6LCK"
    }
```

However, I am struggling to get the "InstanceProfileArn" printed on the console.

So, two things I want to be able to achieve:

- By running `facter ec2_metadata.iam.info.<InstanceProfileArn>`
  from within my instance, I want to be able to see instance profile
  arn printed in the console.
- Secondly, I understand that the way the above command is passed in
  puppet will be slightly different and would look something like
  `$facts[ec2_metadata][iam][info][InstanceProfileArn]`. What
  would be the correct syntax to then be passed into puppet manifest?

Comment: Other than the addition of this `XXXX` which seems like it should be removed from both cases, it seems like you already have the answers to your questions.

Comment: @MattSchuchard the `XXX` was a placeholder in case of anything that was missing and needed to be added but I have now removed it. I have tried `facter ec2_metadata.iam.info.InstanceProfileArn`, but all i get a blank output.

Comment: Ok I think I see the problem here now: the fact has JSON embedded directly into the value of the `info` key. I am unsure if that qualifies as a bug or not, but it does seem odd. You would need to stop at the `info` key and then begin JSON parsing at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [function called `parsejson` in the Puppet Forge `stdlib` module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/4.25.1/readme#parsejson). It can be used to parse a string containing JSON into a Puppet hash. An example using your data:

```sh
$ cat Puppetfile
forge "https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com"
  mod "puppetlabs-stdlib", "4.25.1"
$ r10k puppetfile install
$ cat foo.pp
include stdlib

# should be $info_json = $facts[ec2_metadata][iam][info], but for this example
# we'll use a literal...
$info_json = @(INFO)
{
      "Code" : "Success",
      "LastUpdated" : "2016-08-28T23:12:36Z",
      "InstanceProfileArn" : "arn:aws:iam::750105279227:instance-profile/AnexPrereqs-AnexIAMInstanceProfile-11O8QJAS4XO7S",
      "InstanceProfileId" : "AIPAI6YKKPRVVX2XD6LCK"
}
INFO
$info = parsejson($info_json)
$instance_profile_arn = $info['InstanceProfileArn']
notice($instance_profile_arn)
$ puppet apply --modulepath=modules foo.pp
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): arn:aws:iam::750105279227:instance-profile/AnexPrereqs-AnexIAMInstanceProfile-11O8QJAS4XO7S
[...]
```